# R is not displaying the results

Tags: r, knn

This is the first time I ask a question.

I'm trying to find the best `K` when running `Knn` but the code I got from the professor seems not to be displaying the result of the best `K` and `Rmse`.

Bellow is what I typed on the console. I appreciate the help!

```
#rm(list=ls())
gc()
#setwd('/******/Desktop/Applied/isds 574/R')
dat = read.csv('cleaned.csv', stringsAsFactors=T, head=T)

#dropping Longtitude and Latitude
dat$longitude = NULL 
dat$latitude = NULL
dat$X = NULL


#Factors 

dat$ocean_proxy_dummy = as.factor(dat$ocean_proxy_dummy)

# divide the data into 2 sets: training and validation
set.seed(1) 
id.train = sample(1:nrow(dat), nrow(dat)*.6) 
id.test = setdiff(1:nrow(dat), id.train) 

#KNN2
library(FNN)
Knn.reg.bestK = function(xtrain, xtest, ytrain, ytest, Kmax = 10) { 
  vec.rmse = rep(NA, Kmax) 
  for (K in 1:Kmax) { 
    yhat.test = Knn.reg(xtrain, xtest, ytrain, k)$pred 
    vec.rmse[K] = rmse(yhat.test, ytest) 
  }  
  list(K.opt = which.min(vec.rmse), rmse.min = min(vec.rmse), vec.rmse)
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a look at How to make a great R reproducible example, to modify your question, with a smaller sample taken from your data (check ?dput()). Posting images of your data or no data makes it difficult to impossible for us to help you!

Comment: In the future it's best not to include a `rm(list=ls())`, in the event someone doesn't notice and then deletes everything in their environment.

Comment: Seems not to be displaying the result when? Whatever code you have where you call this function is part of what needs to be here to debug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got this code from your professor, so I'm not sure what the intent of the exercise is. I will tell you that to actually see the results of the function `Knn.reg.bestK()` you will need to call that function on your data.

```
Knn.reg.bestK(xtrain, xtest, ytrain, ytest)
```

But before you do that, you need to set those variables names to the appropriate values.

```
xtrain = id.train$variables #This is a dataframe of predictors
ytrain = id.train$response  #This is your outcome variable
```